# Read and modify files into Centos Hard Disk

Tags: linux, ubuntu, centos, grub

two days ago I had a big problem with my centos server. The problem was so big that I had to remove the hard disk from the server and connect externely with a SATA-USB cable. I created a Ubuntu live-CD, connected my hard drive externly and wooow, it reads it. The problem is that I can't find my real files and folders (e.g.bin, root, home, var,...). In attachments you can find a screenshot what it's into the hard drive. https://postimg.org/image/4crs2qpe3/

How can I find the right tree?
Thanks Davide

Comment: That looks like the boot partition, not the root partition. An explanation of this giant problem would be helpful.

Comment: Thanks. I try to explain. I created a software in java but if I don't start my wildfly service it goes into a infinite loop (bug). I created a sh file and into this file I insert the java -jar command. I put this sh file into the cronjobs task with the @reboot keyword. Now when I start my computer and the login window appears I can't perform the login. I'm sure the problem is related at this shell script with the jar file. The fan start to go very fast and I can't do nothing. This is because I need to access at the harddisk change the jar file name or disable the cronjob at start.

Comment: At login the wildfly service doesn't start but this isn't the problem. I haven't thought at this problem

Comment: Can you edit in a screenshot of the drive in Gparted?

Comment: Or paste in the output of `lsblk`?

Comment: Before putting the external hard drive:
https://s17.postimg.org/sohzomuvj/before.png
After putting the external hard drive:
https://s18.postimg.org/jp5s6ixyh/after.png

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/596835/i-need-help-mounting-an-lvm2-partition-with-14-04-lts-live-usb

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved the problem:
I followed word par word the following link:
http://pissedoffadmins.com/os/mount-unknown-filesystem-type-lvm2_member.html

It's always "fun" seeing that people down vote your question wihtout saying why!
Thanks to Zacharee1